# CSS Auto Width is not Working with Flexbox

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

Greetings Overflowers,

I have an HTML page as follows:

**1.** HTML, BODY, DIVs and SPANs are reset to have `0px border`, `padding`, `margin` and `outline`

**2.** HTML, BODY and DIV elements has `display: -webkit-flex` and `-webkit-flex: 0 0 auto`

**3.** HTML and BODY with `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw`

**4.** Inside BODY, a DIV named `#slider` with `display: -webkit-flex` and -`webkit-flex: 0 0 auto`

**5.** Inside this `#slider`, two DIVs `#sidebar` and `#main` with `display: -webkit-flex` and `-webkit-flex: 0 0 auto` for both, `width: 10rem` for `#sidebar` and `width: 100vw` for `#main`

Problem: I was expecting the width of `#slider` to be `10rem + 100vw`, but it is only `100vw` even if I change the width of `#main` to something smaller such as `50vw`!

Am I missing anything in here?

Kind regards

```css
/*
 unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
 -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
*/

body, div, html, span {
 background: transparent;
 border: 0px;
 cursor: default;
 direction: rtl;
 margin: 0px;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
}

body, html, div {
 background: black;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-flex: none;
}

body, html {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
}

span {
 background: white;
}

.stretch {
 -webkit-flex: 1;
}

.vertical {
 -webkit-flex-flow: column;
}

body>.slider {
 /*-webkit-transform: translateX(10rem);*/
}

#main {
 width: 100vw;
}

body>.slider>#west {
 width: 10rem;
}

#filter-sort.region, #filter-sort-options.region {
 width: 10rem;
}

#doc>#east {
 background: orange;
 height: 6rem;
 width: 6rem;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

#doc>#center {
 background: green;
}

#header, #doc-types {
 height: 2.75rem;
}

#preview {
 max-height: 6rem;
 max-width: 6rem;
}

#search.button, #filter-sort.button {
 background: red;
 width: 3rem;
}

#doc-type {
 background: blue;
 width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body ng:controller="Docs">
  <div class="slider">
   <div id="main" class="region vertical">
    <div id="header" class="region">
     <div id="search" class="button"></div>
     <div id="center" class="region stretch">
     </div>
     <div id="filter-sort" class="button"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="doc-types" class="region">
     <div class="slider">
      <div id="doc-type" class="button"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="docs" class="region">
     <div class="slider stretch vertical">
      <div id="doc" class="region">
       <div id="east" class="region">
        <div id="preview" class="region"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="center" class="region stretch vertical">
        <span id="title" class="label"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="west" class="region">
    <div class="slider">
     <div id="filter-sort" class="region vertical">
      <div id="header" class="region">
       <span id="title" class="label">Filter and Sort</span>
      </div>
      <div id="grades" class="region">
       <div id="center" class="region stretch vertical">
        <span id="grades" class="label">Grade</span><br />
        <span id="grades" class="field"></span>
       </div>
       <div id="west" class="region"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="doc-topic" class="region">
       <div id="center" class="region stretch vertical">
        <span id="doc-topic" class="label">Doc Topic</span><br />
        <span id="doc-topic" class="field"></span>
       </div>
       <div id="west" class="region"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="course" class="region">
       <div id="center" class="region stretch vertical">
        <span id="course" class="label">Course</span><br />
        <span id="course" class="field"></span>
       </div>
       <div id="west" class="region"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="sort" class="region">
       <div id="center" class="region stretch vertical">
        <span id="sort" class="label">Sort</span><br />
        <span id="sort" class="field"></span>
       </div>
       <div id="west" class="region"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="filter-sort-options" class="region vertical">
      <div id="header" class="region">
       <div id="back" class="button"></div>
       <div id="center" class="region stretch">
        <span id="title" class="label">Options</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="grades" class="region">
       <div class="slider vertical">
        <span id="grade" class="label"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="doc-topics" class="region">
       <div class="slider vertical">
        <span id="doc-topic" class="label"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="courses" class="region">
       <div class="slider vertical">
        <span id="course" class="label"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sorts" class="region">
       <div class="slider vertical">
        <span id="sort" class="label"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The markup and the exact CSS used is where?   And which browser(s)?

Comment: Please, see the update. Latest Chrome 27 is used. It seems that when used 100rem instead of 100rem for #main it worked! But I need vw.

Comment: Sorry I meant 100vw instead of 100rem

Comment: Why would `.slider` be 100vw + 10rem wide?  Which `.slider` element, you have multiple?  There are no styles here for the `.slider` element, only for `div`.

Comment: Sorry, I really meant body>.slider

Comment: I need it to resize to its content width

Comment: What is this *supposed* to look like?  It looks like you're overusing Flexbox here, which is causing all sorts of problems.  Plus, your document is invalid (reusing ids).

Comment: My problem is very specific and well stated. Please stick to the scope if you have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fluKI which works as you would expect (Chrome 27)

As far as I can tell from your description, you need to set the width and height of your flex container (`#slider`). Using `flex: 0 0 auto;` on `#slider` won't do what you expect since it is a flex container and not a flex item itself (read: it is not in a flex container).

Also please note that `flex: 0 0 auto;` is the same as saying `flex: none;` which removes the item's flexibility.

Comment: I changed HTML and BODY to be flex containers so that #slider is also a flex item but no luck! However when changed 100vw of #main to 100rem it worked!! But I need vw not rem.